Exporting ODBC/DSN database to CSV from console
I use the ODBC driver and a DSN created for a remote database (Auto02as). I can access the database from Excel with no issues through the "Data -> From other sources" option.
I also created a linked server in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and again, everything is fine; I can run queries.
Screenshots:


But what I really need is to automatically create a CSV every night with a query: SELECT * FROM mytable.
I have tried various commands, like bcp, sqlcmd or osql, but I cant get the job done.
For example, this command fails:
bcp "SELECT * FROM mytable" queryout mytable.csv -d Auto02as -S pc-integral\integral -U admin -P admin


SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'admin'.

Of course, username and password are correct.
How can I make this work?

select * from mytable refers to a local table, so not sure what linked server has to do with anything. I think you're mixing up your concepts.

Aside... Microsoft doesn't provide security updates, bug fixes or technical support for SQL Server 2012 any more. You should probably enact your upgrade plan to get to a modern version.

Are the username and password correct for a Windows/Active Directory account? Because the -U and -P parameters to bcp are for supplying details for a SQL Login account.


I use ... a DSN

Take a look at this excerpt from the bcp documentation:

-D
Causes the value passed to the bcp -S option to be interpreted as a data source name (DSN).

That's probably the option you want to use, as it can ensure you get the right server, database, and driver all in one step. Depending on the DSN it could also keep the credentials out of your script, where they might be sniffed.
bcp "select * from mytable" queryout mytable.csv -D -S Auto02as -c

A final note is some of the examples you find online in this area are formatted poorly, where the space between the command line switch and the value is not visible. You do need a space between options like -S, -U, or -P and the value provided for those options.

Well, getting close. I already had tried the -D option, but it wasn't available in my bcp version (11.0), so after reading your answer, I downloaded a newer version (15.0). I can apply -D now. This is what I get now:

If I write credentials:  El DSN especificó un controlador no compatible.  If I don't write credentials:  SQLState = 08S01, NativeError = 0
Error = [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Socket closed.
